# Spring and DbUnit integration test BeanCreationException Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am writing an integration test using Spring and DBUnit but i have some issues with @Autowired field. I have this **BeanCreationException** which i can not handle. I think the problem comes from this field **private WebApplicationContext wac;**

**ControllerTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:LoginControllerTest2-context.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DatabaseSetup("login.xml")
public class LoginControllerTest2 {

    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:login;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1";
    private static final String USER = "sa";
    private static final String PASS = "";
    private static final String SCHEMA_FILE = "h2.sql";
    private static final String DATASET = "login.xml";

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void createSchema() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        try {
            Connection conn = dataSource().getConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(LoginControllerTest2.class.getResourceAsStream(SCHEMA_FILE));
            RunScript.execute(conn, in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void loadTestData() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webApplicationContextSetup(this.wac).build();
        IDataSet ids = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(LoginControllerTest2.class.getResourceAsStream(DATASET));
        JdbcDatabaseTester databaseTester = new JdbcDatabaseTester(JDBC_DRIVER, JDBC_URL, USER, PASS);
        databaseTester.setSetUpOperation(org.dbunit.operation.DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT);
        databaseTester.setDataSet(ids);
        databaseTester.onSetup();
    }

    private static DataSource dataSource() {
        JdbcDataSource dataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
        dataSource.setURL(JDBC_URL);
        dataSource.setUser(USER);
        dataSource.setPassword(PASS);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Test
    @ExpectedDatabase("login.xml")
    public void testShowForm() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/login")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("/login"))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("../../WebContent/j/login.jsp"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("passportId", nullValue())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("email", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("username", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("hostname", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("pass", isEmptyOrNullString())));
    }

}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="test.loginController" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
                <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver" />
                <property name="url"
                    value="jdbc:h2:mem:login;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=2;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4" />
                <property name="username" value="sa" />
                <property name="password" value="" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="/test/loginController/h2.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

</beans>
```

**Stack Trace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'test.loginController.LoginControllerTest2': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext test.loginController.LoginControllerTest2.wac; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:385)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:95)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:139)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext test.loginController.LoginControllerTest2.wac; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix my problem when i change **@Autowired** anotation on `WebApplicationContext` with **@Resource** anotation.